# JavaScript - split, choose all after a given number

Tags: javascript, string, include, split

I have an dynamic array and I want to exclude the first part of the string, but I don't know how many objects there will be after the first part and I want to include them all in a new string.

```
string = "text.'''hi''','''who''' '''are''' '''you'''. I'm ken and you're barbie"

x = string.split("'''")[1]
```

Is there something I can do to include them all? like [1..?]

I have JQuery but don't think that would be necessary right?

Comment: What is the *result* you're looking for?

Comment: shift or slice both will work

Comment: @Imdad. Except that `slice` create a new array while `shift` does not.

Comment: *"I have JQuery but don't think that would be necessary right?"* Right.

Comment: Yes, @gdoron. But that doesn't matters much you can replace the original array

Comment: @Imdad. Again, except that `shift` is two times faster. take a look on [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/shift-vs-slice2)

Comment: @gdoron, That was a good info. Thanks. I'll prefer shift next time onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shift`:

> Removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

**Code:**

```
x = theString.split("'''");
var firstElement = x.shift();
// Now x is the shifted array.
x[0];
```

Comment: Hmm, I never seemed to get this to work, I got the first part instead of the second part?

Comment: @Philip. `shift` removes the first element and return it, so if you don't want it, **just ignore it's return value.**

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
x = string.split("'''").slice(1);
```

This will return all elements of the array starting at index 1.

Comment: `slice` creates a new array, which is not needed here.

Comment: @pimvdb I updated the right answers to gdoron, I read the post about it being 2x faster than slice. Thank you though! :)